# -w option in PHP curl?

Tags: php

I am converting curl shell command to PHP curl session. 
I have -o NUL and -w "@curl-format.txt".
For -o I am using curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FILE,NULL)
However, I could not find a CURLOPT for the -w option. 
I have

```
      $cmd = "curl -w \"@curl-format.txt\" -o NUL -s \"".$url."\"";

      $output = shell_exec($cmd);
```

I need to turn these into a PHP curl session. 
I am doing like:

```
            $ch = curl_init($url);

            $formatfile=fopen(curl-format.txt,"r");   

            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FILE,NULL);

            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,TRUE);

            curl_exec($ch); 

            curl_close($ch);
```

What should I do for -w?

Comment: are you looking for a particular piece of information that -w returns?

Comment: curl_getinfo($ch) where $ch is your curl instance will return an array some of the same info as the -w option, not sure if it has all of what you need.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Add an example shell code that you are using, so we can better understand what you need and help you achieve what you seek.

Comment: "@curl-format.txt" is the file that contains the format to write after the curl session.  Should I just write

Comment: The values that CLI `curl` uses to replace the variables in the format provided to `-w` are returned by the function [`curl_getinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your `curl_exec($ch)` you can use `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_*);` to return the values of the `CURLINFO_*` constants.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

```
This may be one of the following constants:

CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL - Last effective URL
CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE - Last received HTTP code
CURLINFO_FILETIME - Remote time of the retrieved document, if -1 is returned the time of the document is unknown
CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME - Total transaction time in seconds for last transfer
CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME - Time in seconds until name resolving was complete
CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME - Time in seconds it took to establish the connection
CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME - Time in seconds from start until just before file transfer begins
CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME - Time in seconds until the first byte is about to be transferred
CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT - Number of redirects, with the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option enabled
CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME - Time in seconds of all redirection steps before final transaction was started, with the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option enabled
CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL - With the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option disabled: redirect URL found in the last transaction, that should be requested manually next. With the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option enabled: this is empty. The redirect URL in this case is available in CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL
CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP - IP address of the most recent connection
CURLINFO_PRIMARY_PORT - Destination port of the most recent connection
CURLINFO_LOCAL_IP - Local (source) IP address of the most recent connection
CURLINFO_LOCAL_PORT - Local (source) port of the most recent connection
CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD - Total number of bytes uploaded
CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD - Total number of bytes downloaded
CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD - Average download speed
CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD - Average upload speed
CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE - Total size of all headers received
CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT - The request string sent. For this to work, add the CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT option to the handle by calling curl_setopt()
CURLINFO_REQUEST_SIZE - Total size of issued requests, currently only for HTTP requests
CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT - Result of SSL certification verification requested by setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER
CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD - content-length of download, read from Content-Length: field
CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD - Specified size of upload
CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE - Content-Type: of the requested document, NULL indicates server did not send valid Content-Type: header
CURLINFO_PRIVATE - Private data associated with this cURL handle, previously set with the CURLOPT_PRIVATE option of curl_setopt()
```